# Tridion 9 CMS - Targeting Tab not showing promotions

Tags: smarttarget

I am using Tridion sites 9, And I get **"Failed to Query Elastic search"** when I open the Targeting tab in CMS. XO service logs show some errors saying "Unknown host type". I feel it is not reaching elastic search at localhost:9200 but it is trying some other port.

About the tridion environment:
CMS: Tridion 9 with Smarttarget capability installed
Elastic search: version 5.6.16 with default settings (running on localhost:9200) along with ingest-attachment and analysis-icu plug-ins. Indexes from installElasticsearchIndexes.ps1 were also imported successfully.
XO management service: Installed with and without ES host and port settings.

As I am getting an **"Unknown host exception"**, I feel it is related to Elastic searching host and port setting registration in XO management service. Where can one see which host and port are registered for elastic search in the XO management service?

Comment: Look at the XO management service logs for further analysis?

Comment: Answer to your question: registered elastic search URL passed in the startup parameters & '.\installService.ps1' --auto-register --es.host=localhost --es.port=9200

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have installed XO management service using & '.\installService.ps1' --auto-register --es.host=localhost --es.port=9200 command only with es.host and es.port details included in it. My Smarttarget_conf file does not have any reference to elastic search as the conf file I just copied from installation media. However I could see that my web 8.5 version of this file has reference to Fredhoper and has some configurations for fredhoper. Are those configurations not needed in case of elastic search.

Comment: Yes, It doesn’t needed.